# Data Validation in MVVM light

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

What is the best way to do data validation. Is it a good practice to do validation in view models or should the validation be done in models? and also, what is the best way to implement numeric(decimal) text-box in WPF with MVVM. I am using MVVM Light toolkit.

Comment: I am leaning more towards, doing the validation in view model rather than model because, in the model in my case the model object is being exposed by a service. I have control over the service. but I think it would be better doing it in the view model, because the validation depends on the view. In a view, assigning a value to a property might be required, but optional in the other.

Answer (score 6):

To be able to provide meaningful messages to the user, it is best to make the properties of your ViewModel that should be bound to a TextBox of type string and implement `IDataErrorInfo` on your ViewModel.

In my projects, I am using it like this. I created an interface `IValidateable` (please forgive the name...) which implements IDataErrorInfo. My ViewModel implements this interface:

```
public interface IValidateable : IDataErrorInfo
{
    ObservableCollection<Tuple<string, ValidationError>> InvalidProperties
    { get; }
    bool IsValid { get; }
}
```

All my text boxes use the following style:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
    <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError"
               Value="true">
        <Setter Property="ToolTip"
                Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
      </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
      <Setter.Value>
        <ControlTemplate>
          <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
              <ColumnDefinition Width="90*" />
              <ColumnDefinition Width="20" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Border BorderBrush="Red"
                    BorderThickness="1"
                    CornerRadius="2.75"
                    Grid.Column="0">
              <AdornedElementPlaceholder Grid.Column="0" />
            </Border>
            <TextBlock Foreground="Red"
                       Grid.Column="1"
                       Margin="0"
                       FontSize="12"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       HorizontalAlignment="Left">
              *
            </TextBlock>
          </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
  </Style>
```

This will show a tool tip if the value entered doesn't conform to my rules.

Furthermore, I created a small validation engine which allows to assign rules to the properties of the view model and a base class that automatically validates the property value when a new value is set.
The interface members of `IValidateable` are used to display a meaningful error message to the user when he tries to save an invalid object.

Answer (score 1):

Implement IDataError Info on the class and that will implement two properties Error and this[string columnName] you can implement the second property with your binding errors that you want

```
public class MainViewModel:ViewModelBase,IDataErrorInfo  
{

public string Error
   {
   }
 public string this[string columnName]

 {
  get
      {
         string msg=nulll;
         switch(columnName)
            {
              case "MyProperty": //that will be your binding property
               //choose your validation logic
               if(MyProperty==0||MyProperty==null)
                 msg="My Property is required";
                break;
             }
         return msg;
        }
}
```

Also set ValidateOnError=true on the fields

Comment: To do it in the model in my case, the model object is being exposed by a service. I have control over the service. but I think it would be better doing it in the view model, because the validation depends on the view. In a view, assigning a value to a property might be required, but optional in the other.

Comment: You can do that in Model too! just For Example You have a TextBox that is bound to MyProperty For Local View Model. But If Model Then Objectof the Model.Property. The thing is it IDataErrorInfo Has to be implemented on that HelperClass

Answer (score 0):

If you use IDataErrorInfo for Viewmodel validation - DO NOT FORGET the following:

if your viewmodel has properties other then typeof string and the input in your view can not be converted to the property type - then your input never reach the viewmodel and so the  validation - and the user in front of the view is just thinking: "wtf why i dont see any validation error!"